# Set selected option in ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am developing a web application using C# with asp.net core 2.1.

What I want to achieve is to set the selected option dynamically based on a condition and output the value of (isSelected) variable, here is my code

```
<select asp-for="SelectedLocation" class="form-control">
    @foreach (var location in Model.Locations)
    {
        var isSelected = location.Number == Model.SelectedLocation ? "selected" : "";
        <option value="@location.Number" data-latitude="@Location.Latitude" data-longitude="@location.Longitude">@location.Title</option>
    }
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a ternary operator

`@(location.isSelected? "selected" : "")`

Your code would look like the following:

```
<select asp-for="SelectedLocation" class="form-control">
    @foreach (var location in Model.Locations)
    {
        var isSelected = location.Number == Model.SelectedLocation ? "selected" : "";
        <option value="@location.Number" data-latitude="@Location.Latitude" data-longitude="@location.Longitude" @(location.isSelected? "selected" : "")>@location.Title</option>
    }
</select>
```

What it does is: if `isSelected` is true it'll add a [selected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#Attributes) attribute otherwise it'll add nothing.

You can also break it up and write is as a normal if statement, however I hate razor formatting in VS so I avoid razor as much as I can hence the ternary suggestion.